# swift: correct way to add byte to Data

Tags: swift, nsdata

I've seen some strange gymnastics involving MemoryLayout and arrays when people want to add a plain old byte to a Data/NSData. What is the current accepted practice? Can I not just so something like this?

```
var myData = Data()
let value: UInt8 = 5
myData.append( value)
```

Comment: @vadian Fair point. I didn't realize that it had mutating methods

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. Your syntax is correct and valid.

[`Data`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data) conforms to [`MutableCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mutablecollection), it can be treated as an array of `UInt8` values and it's pretty easily convertible from and to `[UInt8]`.